# Django - Google Maps API Uncaught in promise error when deployed

Tags: javascript, html, django, google-maps, django-templates

Im using the Google maps Javascript Api to display a map on my site. The lat and long are received from two HTML tags which gets the info from a model. The code works and displays a map for every instance of a model. However, it only works 100% of the time when it's on localhost, when I deploy the site to Heroku it only works sometimes. Sometimes the map will show and sometimes it won't. When it doesn't show it gives me an `Uncaught (in promise)` error.

**HTML**

```
<!-- The two tags I'm getting the lat and long from -->
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_lat" name="lat" value="{{object.author.profile.detail_lat}}">
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_lng" name="lng" value="{{object.author.profile.detail_lng}}">

<!--Displays map -->
<div id="main_top">
  <div id="main">
   <div id="right">
     <div id="map"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
          
<script async
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=NICE_TRY=initMap">
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
           <style>
                #main_top {
                    margin-left: 100px;
                }
              #right {
                height: 70%;
                }
              #main {
                height: 400px;
                }
              #map {
               height: 100%;
               width: 900px;
               }
            </style>
```

**Javascript**

```
            function initMap() {
                var lat = +document.getElementById('hidden_lat').value   
                var lng = +document.getElementById('hidden_lng').value
                const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                  zoom: 12,
                  disableDefaultUI: true,
                  gestureHandling: "none",
                  zoomControl: false,
                  center: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
                  
                });
                const image = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Pan_Blue_Circle.png";
                const beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
                map,
                icon: image,
                });
              }
```

[The error thats showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXnn3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes across a similiar issue. The API combined with heroku server delays were causing a race condition, so instead of using `async` on the API script use `defer`.